# Return Function and Add additional Column

Tags: sql-server-2008, function, cursor

My Current table is:

```
USERID  Department    NAME           actualdate
 522    xyz department  John Wayne    2/17/14 8:34
 522    xyz department  John Wayne    2/17/14 11:21
 789    xyz department  Bill Smith    2/17/14 9:41
 789    xyz department  Bill Smith    2/17/14 11:16
 789    xyz department  Bill Smith    2/17/14 11:50
 789    xyz department  Bill Smith    2/17/14 12:18
 856    xyz department  Raul Castil   2/17/14 9:25
```

I want to create a function that allows me to enter the user id and return the data from that user.  However, I would like to take the first row and grab the actual date and then  store it in a column'check in' and the also take the last row  and store it in a column call it 'check out'.

Basically for each day I want to record the user check in time and check out time for each day an employee worked.

This is what I  have so far"

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetEmployeeTime]
(   
@useridd int
)
RETURNS @RtnValue TABLE 
(
    useridd int,
    deptname varchar(max),
    emplname varchar(100),
    actualDate datetime,
    checkIn datetime,--first row of the actual date goes here
    checkOut datetime -- last row of the actual date goes here
)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE  @userid int,@checkin datetime, @checkout datetime;
    DECLARE @useridAndDate   varchar(max), @useridAndDate2 varchar(max);

    DECLARE Curs CURSOR FOR 
    select ch.USERID AS useridd,ch.CHECKTIME as actualdate
    from CHECKINOUT ch
    left join USERINFO ui on ui.USERID=ch.USERID
    left join DEPARTMENTS dep on dep.DEPTID=ui.DEFAULTDEPTID

 OPEN Curs;
 FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO  @useridd, @actualdate;
 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0

 ---so confuse here to loop through rows to record only first and last row.
--- adding userid and date so i can differentiate between dates as well as userid

 set @useridAndDate= @useridd + @actualdate
   --if @useridAndDate != @useridAndDate2
--- or if @useridd =useridd2 and @actualdate = @actualdate2
   --begin
   --end

FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO @useridd,@actualdate
close Curs;
deallocate Curs;
Return;

END
```

I want the end result to look like this:

```
USERID    Department       NAME    actualdate       checkin       checkout    
 522     xyz department   John Wayne    2/17/14 8:34   2/17/14 8:34   2/17/14 11:21
 789     xyz department   Bill Smith    2/17/14 9:41   2/17/14 9:41   2/17/14 12:18
 856     xyz department   Raul Castil   2/17/14 9:25   2/17/14 9:25
```

Please help

Comment: How is this question different from your previous question?

Comment: Did you find solution for your query..

Comment: mo i have not..i am still working on it.. I know i can get the min and max time by userid, but i want to get the min and max time by EACH DATE correlating to user id